# How do I conditionally disable an option in a form select in React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, forms, for-loop

So I have been trying to give three sets of options that are rendered from the same data table, and if one option is selected in the first form select, then it should be disabled in the second and third form select. The three form select options are rendered using a for loop as shown and the

my handleChange method and the final rendered Form Select is written like so:

```
handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.data.length; i++) {
        if (this.state.data[i].securityQuestion === e.target.value) {
            if (e.target.name === "questionOne") {
                this.setState({
                    questionOneId: this.state.data[i].securityQuestionId
                })
            } else if (e.target.name === "questionTwo") {
                    alert(i)
                this.setState({
                    questionTwoId: this.state.data[i].securityQuestionId
                })
            }
        } else {
            this.setState({
                questionThreeId: this.state.data[i].securityQuestionId
            })
        }
    }
}

<FormGroup>
    <FormSelect onChange={this.handleChange} name="questionOne" value={this.state.questionOne}>
        {this.state.data && this.state.data.map((item, index) =>

            <option key={item.securityQuestionId}>{item.securityQuestion}</option>)
        }
    </FormSelect>
</FormGroup>
<FormGroup>
    <FormInput id="feInputAddress8"
        name="answerOne"
        value={this.state.answerOne}
        invalid={this.state.answerOne === ""}
        valid={this.state.answerOne !== undefined}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        placeholder="Answer.." />
    <FormFeedback> Answer is mandatory.</FormFeedback>
</FormGroup>

<FormGroup>
    <FormSelect onChange={this.handleChange} name="questionTwo" value={this.state.questionTwo} >
        {this.state.data && this.state.data.map((item, index) =>
            <option key={item.securityQuestionId} onClick={() => this.getQuestionData(item.securityQuestionId, item.securityQuestion)}>{item.securityQuestion}</option>)
        }
    </FormSelect>
</FormGroup>
<FormGroup>
    <FormInput id="feInputAddress8"
        name="answerTwo"
        value={this.state.answerTwo}
        invalid={this.state.answerTwo === ""}
        valid={this.state.answerTwo !== undefined}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        placeholder="Answer.." />
    <FormFeedback> Answer is mandatory.</FormFeedback>
</FormGroup>

<FormGroup>
    <FormSelect onChange={this.handleChange} name="questionThree" value={this.state.questionThree}>
        {this.state.data && this.state.data.map((item, index) =>
            <option key={item.securityQuestionId}>
                {item.securityQuestion}
            </option>)
        }
    </FormSelect>
</FormGroup>

<FormGroup>
    <FormInput id="feInputAddress8"
        name="answerThree"
        value={this.state.answerThree}
        invalid={this.state.answerThree === ""}
        valid={this.state.answerThree !== undefined}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        placeholder="Answer.." />
    <FormFeedback> Answer is mandatory.</FormFeedback>
</FormGroup>
```

Comment: Please mention the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add a `chosen: false` param to your item in your data state you can then set the state to `data.item[x].chosen = true` when an option is chosen, this will rerender the page.

in the render you can write your `option` like this:

`<option key={...} onClick={...} disabled={item.chosen} >{...}</option>`